# Draw visible text on image regardless of image color

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

I want to print text on a 24bpp image using DrawString(). The problem is if I choose white as text color the text is nearly invisible in brighter image areas. If I choose red as text color the text is nearly invisible in image areas which contains more red. And so on.

What I want to achieve is that the text is visible in any circumstances. What I tried was tho draw the text with bold font and then draw the text using the same font but regular again. But the bold text is slightly wider so this is not a solution.

But what is the solution? Is there any?

Thanks!

Comment: Is drawing an opaque white background rectangle behind the text acceptable in your situation?

Comment: I don't remember where I heard it, but from what I remember, the best way to make sure that text is always visible would be to have white text with a black border.

Comment: Can the color differ much within the same string? Or is it reasonable to assume that one color per string will be sufficient?

Comment: The easiest possible way to do this would be to make a border around the string text (i.e black border with white text - on white bg only black outline shows; on black - only white shows). I'm not sure if draw string has the option for this but you can always overlap two strings with one marginally bigger than the other to fake this

Comment: Make the color of the text a negative image of the one behind it. The text will always be visible if you do that.

Comment: I suggest drawing the text twice: Once in a dark and once in a bright color, set apart 1 pixel up & left. If your font is very small and only 1 pixel wide on many strokes then using triple drawing will help two outer ones in one colr (dark) and the 3rd one in the middle (bright)

Comment: @LeeHarrison: that doesn't work for gray values. The negative of `(0x80,0x80,0x80)` is `(0x7f,0x7f,0x7f)`. There exists however a method to calculate the most distant color.

Comment: Good point @CommuSoft! I had never considered that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the image doesn't differ much such that one can assume you will paint a string in a region with a quite solid color, you can use the following solution.

You can first use an algorithm to calculate the most different color from another color as follows:

```
public static byte MostDifferent (byte original) {
    if(original < 0x80) {
        return 0xff;
    } else {
        return 0x00;
    }
}
public static Color MostDifferent (Color original) {
    byte r = MostDifferent(original.R);
    byte g = MostDifferent(original.G);
    byte b = MostDifferent(original.B);
    return Color.FromArgb(r,g,b);
}
```

Now that we have done that, we must calculate the average color within the region where the `string` will be drawn. You can do this on `Bitmap` level with:

```
public static unsafe Color AverageColor (Bitmap bmp, Rectangle r) {
    BitmapData bmd = bmp.LockBits (r, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    int s = bmd.Stride;
    int cr = 0;
    int cg = 0;
    int cb = 0;
    int* clr = (int*)(void*)bmd.Scan0;
    int tmp;
    int* row = clr;
    for (int i = 0; i < r.Height; i++) {
        int* col = row;
        for (int j = 0; j < r.Width; j++) {
            tmp = *col;
            cr += (tmp >> 0x10) & 0xff;
            cg += (tmp >> 0x08) & 0xff;
            cb += tmp & 0xff;
            col++;
        }
        row += s>>0x02;
    }
    int div = r.Width * r.Height;
    int d2 = div >> 0x01;
    cr = (cr + d2) / div;
    cg = (cg + d2) / div;
    cb = (cb + d2) / div;
    bmp.UnlockBits (bmd);
    return Color.FromArgb (cr, cg, cb);
}
```

Finally the algorithm first measures the rectangle where the string will be painted, next it determines the most different color and finally paints the string with that color:

```
public static void DrawColorString (this Graphics g, Bitmap bmp, string text, Font font, PointF point) {
    SizeF sf = g.MeasureString (text, font);
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle (Point.Truncate (point), Size.Ceiling (sf));
    r.Intersect (new Rectangle(0,0,bmp.Width,bmp.Height));
    Color brsh = MostDifferent (AverageColor (bmp, r));
    g.DrawString (text, font, new SolidBrush (brsh), point);
}
```

Now you can call the method for instance as:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("Foo.png");
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
g.DrawColorString (bmp, "Sky", new Font ("Arial", 72.0f), new PointF (600.0f, 150.0f));
g.DrawColorString (bmp, "Sand", new Font ("Arial", 72.0f), new PointF (600.0f, 450.0f));
bmp.Save ("result.jpg");
```

This result for instance in:

[image]

Comment: Hi,great, used your MostDifferent approach. Great help, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I suggest drawing the text two (or three) times: Once in a dark and once in a bright color, set apart 1 or 2 pixels up & left, depending on the font size.

If your font is very small and only 1 pixel wide on many strokes then using triple drawing will help: two outer ones in one color (dark) and the 3rd one in the middle (bright)

```
Random R = new Random();
private void pictureBox2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    // using a loop for create random locations..:
    for (int i=0; i< 33; i++)
    {
        Point pt = new Point(R.Next(pictureBox2.ClientSize.Width), 
                             R.Next(pictureBox2.ClientSize.Width));

        e.Graphics.DrawString("Hello World", Font, Brushes.Black, pt.X - 1, pt.Y - 1);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Hello World", Font, Brushes.Black, pt.X + 1, pt.Y + 1);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Hello World", Font, Brushes.White, pt.X , pt.Y);
    }
}
```

Here is an example with triple drawing

:[image]

(Note that the original looks a lot crisper that what I see in the browser. You may want to download it to check..)

If your images may contain very much noise and the font must be rather small, then adding a solid background behind the text will work better.

Comment: You could also just write the black text as a bold font (maybe with a font increase) then the white font, center both calls so they line up correctly.  What they hell is that a picture of: a car accident?

Comment: I don't think the lining up would work for anything longer than a few characters. The OP had tried something like that and the characters didn't line up well. - Not an accident (yet); one in  a series of [remarkable kludges](http://www.heise.de/autos/artikel/Die-skurrilsten-Eigenreparaturen-1717729.html?bild=4;view=bildergalerie)